# Create button to get value from input and open default email client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, email

I have a button in a form that I want to collect the value (which is an email address) from a nearby input and construct an email using the default email client. It would be a similar function to your standard email link:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?Subject=Test" target="_blank">
```

Only in my instance, it's a button constructing the email and it also collects a value. What I have so far:

HTML

```
<input class="an-input" type="text">
<button class="ui-state-default inputButton an-button">SEND</button>
```

JS:

```
var ACEbutton = conf._input.find('.an-button');
ACEbutton.click(function() {
    var inputValue = conf._input.find('input').val();
    var subject = "This is a subject";
    var subjectEncoded = encodeURIComponent(subject);
    document.getElementById('emailMe').href = "mailto:'+inputValue+'?subject=" + subjectEncoded;
} );
```

The code as it stands isn't opening the email.

Answer (score 1):

You should end the string statement before concatenating it. If you start a string with double quotes, you should end it with double quotes. Same goes for single quotes.

```
document.getElementById('emailMe').href = "mailto:"+inputValue+"?subject=" + subjectEncoded;
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('emailMe').href = "mailto:'+inputValue+'?subject=" + subjectEncoded;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
//fix syntax like Ricardo said
document.getElementById('emailMe').href = "mailto:"+inputValue+"?subject=" + subjectEncoded;
//trigger email client
document.getElementById("emailMe").click();
```